# Html.fromHtml() force to not remove unknown tags

Tags: java, android, html

When I use `Html.fromHtml(source)` method on text, all unknown tags are removed (unfortunately I have a case, where emoticons are defined in <> symbols e.g. `<cat>`). Is there any way to force Html.fromHtml() to keep unknown tags instead of removing them?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can write a custom [HtmlTagHandler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.TagHandler.html) to handle your custom tag, either you still keep it in current source or convert it into something easier to process.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom [TagHandler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.TagHandler.html) whos `handleTag` method is called when the parser comes across a tag it doesn't recognize.

API 1+

`Spanned fromHtml (String src, Html.ImageGetter Html.TagHandler tagHandler)`

*Deprecated in API 24*

API 24+

`Spanned fromHtml (String src, int flags,  Html.ImageGetter imgGetter, Html.TagHandler tagHandler)`

https://www.mohammedlakkadshaw.com/blog/handling-custom-tags-in-android-using-html-taghandler.html/

Comment: Yup that could help me track tags I can predict (emoticons) but what about tags which I can't predict? I want to keep all of them event if it is some kind of bizarre  <fsaasdasz> tag.